# How can I move things without having to select the move tool?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm a complete newbie to Blender and I am going through the most recent tutorials on youtube.

Just got to the object and edit mode tutorial.

At 0:37 the instructor picks the four top points on a box, then moves it round while still in the box select mode.

How does he do that?

I am only able to do the same thing after clicking on the "move" button. How does he do it without clicking on the move button?

Comment: Press G with the vertices selected and you can move them around. G is the hotkey for movement / translation.

Comment: Thank you!!! :)